Error while adding service provider in WSO2
Initially I added a service provider with oauth ID as "test" and later changed the oauth ID to "demo" for inbound oauth configuration
However now when I try add the same SP with oauth ID as "test" , I end up with following error

{"code":"APP-50001","message":"Error importing application from XML file.","description":"An OAuth application already exists with test as consumer key","traceId":"fb76c4f2-b0e5-4d2e-b8a0-623baa2ef69d"}"}

I verified other SP and I dont see consumer key as test for any other SP

Hi Devaddy, how did you update the client ID?

It is a kubernetes deployment, I have the XML file as configmap and update the client ID in the configmap itself
